# How to handle anchors (bookmarks) with Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm looking for a smart way to handle in-page anchors with Vue Router. Consider the following:

```
<router-link to="#app">Apply Now</router-link>
<!-- some HTML markup in between... -->
<div id="app">...</div>
```

The "scroll to anchor" behavior [described in the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) works fine except:

- When you click on the anchor, it brings you down to the `div id="app"`. Now scroll away from the `div` back to the anchor and try clicking it again -- this time you will **not** jump down to the `div`. In fact, the anchor will retain the class `router-link-active` and the URL will still contain the hash `/#app`;
- With the steps above, if you refresh the page (the URL will still contain the hash) and click on the anchor, nothing will happen either.

This is very unfortunate from the UX perspective because a potential customer has to manually scroll all the way down again to reach the application section.

I was wondering if Vue Router covers this situation. For reference, here's my router:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash }
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I haven't found anything in the resources to solve your issue but you could utitlize the `$route.hash` in your `mounted` hook of the component that holds your `<router-view></router-view>` to solve the refresh issue.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  mounted: function()
  {
    // From testing, without a brief timeout, it won't work.
    setTimeout(() => this.scrollFix(this.$route.hash), 1);
  },
  methods: {
    scrollFix: function(hashbang)
    {
      location.hash = hashbang;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then to solve the issue of second clicks you could use the `native` modifier and bind to your `<router-link></router-link>`.  It's a fairly manual process but will work.

```
<router-link to="#scroll" @click.native="scrollFix('#scroll')">Scroll</router-link>
```

There may also be something you could do with the router's `afterEach` method but haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: This is great! I wish there was a way to assign the click event to the router itself. I tried `beforeEach`, but it doesn't seem to fire with bookmarks.

Comment: @Alex May be worth adding an issue on the github repo to see if there is a better approach, which i'm almost certain there is.

Comment: Asked same question on [Vue.js forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-handle-anchors-bookmarks-with-vue-router/14563). I believe on Github, they tend to refer you back to StackOverflow and the forum unless it's a bug report of some sort :)

Comment: Here's your answer as a one liner: 
    `mounted(){
      setTimeout(() => location.href = this.$route.hash, 1);
    },`

Comment: @RoccoB good suggestion.  I edited the answer to add the arrow function  but kept the method so it's the same across the mounted hook and click event.

Comment: @StevenB. Good point, I guess what I wrote is not exactly logically equivalent to what you have above :-). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not sure why this is the "fix". When setting `location.href` it will reload the entire page and throw you into a reload loop. This is not a solution.

Comment: @rebz It should be `location.hash` which will prevent the reload loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you're already on the route with the hash, you can just set it to scroll to the target.

(also note `scrollBehavior()` method in your router won't get called if you're already on the route you're trying to go to).

```
export default {
  methods: {
    anchorHashCheck() {
      if (window.location.hash === this.$route.hash) {
        const el = document.getElementById(this.$route.hash.slice(1))
        if (el) {
          window.scrollTo(0, el.offsetTop)
        }
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.anchorHashCheck()
  },
}
```

Then add a `@click.native` to listen to events on the anchor in your `<router-link>`,

```
<router-link :to="{hash: '#some-link'}" @click.native="anchorHashCheck">
  Some link
</router-link>
```

Comment: @click.native is deprecated is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution which is more resusable IMO:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'home' }, undefined, () => { location.href = this.$route.hash })
```

As the 3rd argument is the abort() function, it may have unwanted side effects though..

If you want to use it globally, add a function to your Router:

```
pushWithAnchor: function (routeName, toHash) {
    const fromHash = Router.history.current.hash
    fromHash !== toHash || !fromHash
    ? Router.push({ name: routeName, hash: toHash })
    : Router.push({ name: routeName, hash: fromHash }, undefined, () => { window.location.href = toHash })
  }
```

And use it in components with:

```
this.$router.options.pushWithAnchor('home', '#fee-calculator-section')
```

Within a template you could do something like:

```
<a @click="this.$router.options.pushWithAnchor('home', '#fee-calculator-section')"></a>
```

Sadly you cant use a scroll offset though

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```
<router-link to="/about" @click.native="scrollFix('#team')" >The team</router-link>
```

And this:

```
methods: {
    scrollFix: function(hash) {
      setTimeout(() => $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000), 1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a real reason to add jquery to vue project? :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked about anchors and you have an answer already. However, the below function should work for both anchors and regular links. It allows you to scroll to the position of the first instance of the Component a Route has been matched to. I wrote it to see if I could by-pass using a hash while retaining anchor-style scrolling.

```js
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.matched) {
    const children = to.matched[1].parent.instances.default.$children;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      let child = children[i];
      if (child.$options._componentTag === to.matched[1].components.default.name) {
        return {
          x: child.$el.offsetLeft,
          y: child.$el.offsetTop
        };
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
}
```

The reason I'm using `parent.instances` is because the `to.matched[1].instances` value is empty. It's not the most elegant solution, though it might help someone else out there.

Note: This only works when you want to scroll the first instance of a Component.