# Internal links in Vue.js: Using the vue-router to jump to a specific section in a view with an id

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Home view and a Blog view.
Trying to use a `<router-link>` to jump from the Home view to a specific section in the Blog view.
The section looks like `<section id="fundamentals" class="section">`

In html I believe it would work like `<a href="/blog/#fundamentals">Jump to specific blog section</a>`
How can I replicate this using the vue-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs for scroll behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior). In particular, the discussion of scrolling to a hash:

```
If you want to simulate the "scroll to anchor" behavior:

scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      selector: to.hash
      // , offset: { x: 0, y: 10 }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201014/how-to-handle-anchors-bookmarks-with-vue-router/45206192) and use the `@click.native` property of the router as specified on the top answer. You could also use the vue-scrollto plugin which is much easier. It's as easy as

```
<a href="#" v-scroll-to="'#element'">Scroll to #element</a>
 
<div id="element">
    Hi. I'm #element.
</div>
```

after you setup the plugin.