# Vue router - path #ID scrollBehavior

Tags: vue.js, router, fullpage.js

I have created a MENU where I link via `<router-link>` but certain links are linked to the same page using (anchors).
When I'm on the Work page and I click on the `#services` section, which is on the Bio page, the section is displayed correctly, but if I want to go to the `services` section on the Bio page, the URL just changes, but it won't go to the right section for me.

noubtest.com

**NAVIGATION**

```
<router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link bio" :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Bio</router-link>
<router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link link2" :to="{ name: 'Services' }">Services</router-link>
<router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link link2" :to="{ name: 'SelectedWork' }">Work</router-link>
```

**ROUTER**

```js
{
  path: "/home",
  name: "Home",
  component: Home,
  meta: {
    title: "Bio",
    requiresAuth: false,
  },
},
{
  path: "/home#fifthPage",
  name: "Services",
  component: Home,
  meta: {
    title: "Services",
    requiresAuth: false,
  },
},

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
 
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = `${to.meta.title} | YounesFilm`;
  next();
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let admin = null;
  if (user) {
    let token = await user.getIdTokenResult();
    admin = token.claims.admin;
  }
  if (to.matched.some((res) => res.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (user) {
      if (to.matched.some((res) => res.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
        if (admin) {
          return next();
        }
        return next({ name: "Home" });
      }
      return next();
    }
    return next({ name: "Home" });
  }
  return next();
});

export default router;
```

How can I click through the page between sections?

Comment: **NAVIGATION**<router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link bio" :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Bio</router-link>
        <router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link link2" :to="{ name: 'Services' }">Services</router-link>
        <router-link v-show="!mobile" class="link link2" :to="{ name: 'SelectedWork' }">Work</router-link>

Answer (score 0):

With a few research, I found two things that could help you.

First, this error is known and discussed on [github vue-router issues page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1668).

Second, I found that [Workaround on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-anchor-router-link), and you could probably give it a try.

EDIT

I found another solution to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206192/18277469).

And from [that page](https://reactgo.com/scroll-to-anchor-tags-vue-router/), I found a scrollBehavior example like this:

```
scrollBehavior: function (to) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      selector: to.hash
    }
  }
}
```

And if it still doesn't work, you could try to use
`:to="{ name: 'Home', hash: 'fifthPage'}"`.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You must switch your VueRouter from `hash` mode to `history` mode of routing - then hashtags will work but in a different way.
Your routes should not have a hash symbol `#` inside their path - instead, you should provide it under the `hash` attribute of the route link:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: pathName, hash: '#text' }">
    Jump to content
</router-link>
```

But this alone is not enough. You also need to alter the `scrollBehavior` of the VueRouter:

```js
import { routes } from './routes.js';

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) 
    {
        if (savedPosition) 
        {
            return savedPosition;
        }
        if (to.hash) 
        {
            return { selector: to.hash }; // <==== the important part
        }
        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me either...if I use <a href> everything works as it should, but it limits me in further use

Comment: UPDATE: if I use your solution, scrolling to the correct hash does not work even after refreshing the page

Comment: The solution requires `history` mode of VueRouter - in `hash` mode there is a conflict. You can also try swapping the checks for `to.hash` and `savedPosition`.

Comment: Hi, can you try to explain me on this example please? const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
 
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
});

Comment: If you are trying to navigate from route `/homepage` to route `/homepage#bottom` then VueRouter will not call the `scrollBehavior` function. Perhaps you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176918/5962802